# Why do I care what the <start-point> is when I create a new Git branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

Let's say that, somewhere inside some **Project's** Local Working-Directory, I have this file-path:

```
[...]/subdir23/file09
```

Let's further say that the **fishlegs** branch **is** able to see that subdir and file but the **chickenlips** branch is **not** able to see that subdir and file.

Now, let's say that I want to do some feature-work on **file09**; so, I need to create a feature-branch.  It is my understanding that I want to specify **fishlegs** as the  branch, *rather than* **chickenlips** ...

```
git  branch  MyFeatureBranch  fishlegs
```

... and this is because, IF I use the start-point of **fishlegs** then, when I *switch* to **MyFeatureBranch** to start doing the feature-work, I **will** be able to see the
**[...]/subdir23/file09** path.  But IF I were to use the start-point of **chickenlips** then, when I *switch* to **MyFeatureBranch**, I will **not** be able to see that path.

Is the above correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, sure. A branch is just a pointer to a commit, so a new branch without any work on it is identical to the source commit. What's got you confused about that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I think that I should have added one more detail:  I am under the impression that my above description is *literally* the **only** reason for caring about precisely which existing branch is used as the <start-point>.  I've been tasked with helping some of my colleagues to learn about Git & Gitlab.  We are all new to it.  So, I want to get this particular point completely clear.  Thanks.

Comment: `git branch foo` and `git branch foo HEAD` are equivalent. The explicit starting-point argument lets you avoid an unnecessary checkout. Usually, `HEAD` will be a branch head whose state is what you want to "branch off" from, which is why you can default to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the 2 comments --one from **isherwood** and the other from **Frost**-- I believe that I can regard the answer to my question as precisely what Frost wrote:

"Yes, that is correct."

(For clarification, simply read my original post, itself.)

Comment: Your condition here (that the files in question exist so that you can do work on/with them) is necessary, but might not be sufficient. What if there are ten branch names and *five* of them, when checked out, get you some version(s) of the file(s) you want? You've eliminated the other five (they're clearly wrong as they lack the files) but how will you select between the remaining five?

Comment: The real trick here, which takes a while as a beginner to get the hang of, is that Git itself really doesn't care about the *branch names*. What Git really cares about are the *commits*. The names help you (and Git) *find* commits you want, but sometimes none of the names you have are the right one. In this case you'll need to find the right commit by its raw hash ID, and use that. In *most* cases, one of the existing names, or remote-tracking names like `origin/something`, is the, or at least "a", right name, though.